# How to append text from a JavaScript event into Ruby syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to dynamically update Ruby syntax on the front-end based on a select value with an `eventListener` or `onchange`.

Here is my example:

Ruby:

```
<%= if @model.attribute == {javascript_text} %>
```

and the `{javascript_text}` would be able to be dynamically updated based on an event change for a select.

Similar to how this works, but instead of appending the text to the `div`, it will append it into the Ruby syntax:

```
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
<option value="1">dog</option>
<option value="12">cat</option>
<option value="11">bird</option>
</select>

<div id="test"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myNewFunction(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dkun/1

Is there any way to be able to do this?

Comment: [Hack?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEkrWRHCDQU) You'd need a time machine since the server renders out the JavaScript long before the browser gets it to render it. The Ruby process is long gone by the time that kicks in.

Comment: Since this is Ruby on Rails, use "UJS" (Unobtrusive JavaScript), as in jQuery and bindings. If you need a server call to occur *after* a JavaScript function has run, use AJAX to make a request and then handle the response in JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman im dead

Comment: I know it can be a bit confusing if you're looking at the source and figure you can flip between languages arbitrarily, but that's not the case. The Rails server must emit a fully-formed, complete document and hand it off to the browser for execution. For any sort of communication after that fact you need AJAX to make another request or [Action Cable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) to open a real-time connection.

Comment: Remember HTTP is all about request-response. Once the request is handled and the response is sent you have no further interaction with the document.

Comment: What happens `if @model.attribute == {javascript_text}`? Does a form change, or different text is displayed? This can all be done using Javascript. Remember that the Ruby code never runs in the browser. So, it is impossible to re-run it upon some page action

Comment: To solve this problem we need to know a bit more about this `@model.attribute` comparison. Are you searching the database for a particular selection? Are you checking how to render out a bit of text depending on their selection?

Comment: @tadman thank you so much.  this may help.  I also am going to see if i can solve my issue but opening modals via ajax.  My goal is to dynamically load records and images based off form changes and all on one page with modals.. but maybe instead i can RESTfuly do it with modals instead of using a ton of javascript.

Comment: It's possible. It really depends on what you're building. Remember it's 2020 and things like [React](https://reactjs.org), [Vue](https://vuejs.org) and [Ember](https://emberjs.com) exist, all of which work very well on top of Rails. If you're building a big client-side app these can help frame your thinking.

Comment: The approach i am doing is not a good one.  I was thinking to display an associated model based on the if statement if the associated_model.attribute_id matches the value of the select change.

Comment: You're right @tadman --- I am building a concept for an in-house app that will end up being refactored by a professional dev later this year.  So i just need something that works for them to go off of

Comment: By that, I mean, I am a beginner at react.  I did learn the syntax but never put much practice to it

Comment: You can save in hidden values the possibilities of the attribute and opt for JavaScript blocks of code.

Comment: @JuanseCora I've been doing that with `pluck` but it's honestly a bit messy.  I actually just implemented loading modals with javascript dynamically and seems to actually be the best way to go about this (aside from other javascript methods like react and vue).  Goodthing I made this post so i realize how bad what i was doing was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Your rails code runs on the server and your javascript runs on the client*. So you are thinking about the whole thing completely wrong.

Your rails server just responds to an incoming HTTP request from the client. It then matches the request with a controller and the controller renders a view into a string buffer which is sent as the payload of the response. To your server the page is just a string built by rendering a erb template.

The client receives the response and parses it into a html document. It runs any javascript included within the document (inline and linked).

When the user changes the select this is happening on their computer. The only way to tell the server of the change is for the client to send a new request which can be either syncronous (a form submission or a by clicking a link which replaces the current page) or asyncrous (an AJAX request sent through javascript). If your javascript is just linking together two inputs that exist on the page there is no reason you have to get the server involved at all.

Websockets (ActionCable) is a whole other cup of tea and not really something you should get into until you actually understand the basics of HTTP and the client server interaction.

(*) Yes you can run javascript on your server with node.js (or any of the other js runtimes). But that doesn't change the fact that the user is changing the select on their machine - not on the server.